# Session Tracking - If User Is Logged In

Tags: php, facebook, session, tracking

I'm trying to implement Facebook authentication into my web project. I've managed to get login working just fine, but I am unsure as to how to proceed further.

I need to continuosly make sure that the user is logged in and authenticated while using my application. In previous projects I've achieved this by storing userid and password in cookies and run a check against the mysql "users" table each time a php page was called.

I haven't found any tutorial which describes how to do this with Facebook, as all the tutorials ends after login is complete.

I'm thinking of storing the FB_UID in a php session variable, and then check it against the mysql "users" table to see if it's correct each time a php page is called. However I get a feeling that this is unneccessary, and that the FB session variables can be used for this purpose. Any thoughts or insights appreciated!

I will of course implement https when the site goes online due to php session security issues.

Comment: How did you implement the Facebook authentication?

Comment: *"storing userid and password in cookies"*, beginner mistakes #1 and #2.

Comment: The principle here is the same as your other projects. You need a unique identifier (Facebook UserId) to store in session to check against a trusted datasource (a database or FB itself). Please don't store it in cookies, and please use a salted hash of some sort to validate it. :)

Comment: @Vivek I'm using the php API to retrieve the FB_UID and compare it against my users table. If it matches any of the users in the table, I've got a logged in user. If not, I'll register a new user using user_data from FB, and proceed from there.

Comment: @netcoder I've learned a few things since my last web app, one of them being not to store uid/pwd in cookies :)

Any thoughts on which datasource is preferable, db or fb?

Comment: @aanders77: DB is most likely faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While authenticating a facebook user, if the `FB_UID` matches your `users` table, have a php session variable store the `FB_UID` and check if the php session variable is set or not, every time the page loads. Finally when the user logs out, unset the php session variable.

Answer (score 2):

When the user login to his/her facebook account, authenticate that use against database (check username, password, ...). If they match, create session(s). From that point use session for the authentication.

With the above way, people can hijack session. Enabling cookie can prevent it.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [FB.Event.subscribe()](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/) call. From the website:-

Global Events to which you can subscribe:

- auth.login - fired when the user logs in
- auth.authResponseChange - fired when the authResponse changes
- auth.statusChange - fired when the status changes...